# Is there any way to receive a notification when the user powers off the device?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I need to know when the user powers off his/her phone.  Are there any broadcasts (or similar) that notify when the user's phone is powered off?

Comment: @BenIOs: like your code won't run anymore, joking! maybe if you make your application write on a file or do a ajax call every n minute and analyze that after.

Comment: There is probably some log written somewhere for that.  I'd be very surprised if there wasn't.

Comment: Very off-topic: The wording made me think of the BeOS function `is_computer_on()`: when the computer is on, it returns 1, otherwise the result is undefined.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use the [`ACTION_SHUTDOWN` Intent](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN) which is broadcast when the phone is about to shutdown.  The documentation says:

> Apps will not normally need to handle this, since the foreground activity will be paused as well.

In other words, if you respond to all the lifecycle events for your Activity appropriately, there's no need to use this unless you really want to do something specific related to shutdown.

The `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` Intent was introduced in API Level 4, in other words **it'll only be sent on phones running Android 1.6 or later**.

You'll trap the Broadcast with a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).  It will look something like this:

```
public class ShutdownReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Insert code here
    }

}
```

You'll also need an entry in your Manifest like the following:

```
<receiver android:name=".ShutdownReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Depending on what you're doing, another option would be to use the [`ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` Intent](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) which is sent when the phone is restarted.

Comment: i did same as above but nothing happend...i added Log.v("Shutdown Event","Device shutting down"); but not able to do anything on this event, kindly give any suggestion..thanks

Comment: @DeepSan - I would make sure your Manifest entry points to the correct class.

Comment: @DaveWebb- Sir, will you plz explain what is the mean of your comment, i did not get..will you plz tell what should i do to save shut down time in a text file...

Comment: @DeepSan The `android:name` in your `<receiver>` entry must be the class name of the `BroadcastReceiver` you have implemented. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: @DaveWebb- Hello sir, the issue i have been already resolve,there was small mistake in code. i fixed now everything i fine..thanks for your precious time and valuable ideas...

Comment: Is there any guarantee your code will be given enough time to complete using this? I.e. does the shutdown continue or will it wait/block for your receiver to finish doing whatever it needs to?

Comment: @matt5784 take a look at the source code to the shutdown process in this link.  They give you 10 seconds to do what you need to do before shutting down the radio, unmounting the fs etc: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/java/com/android/server/power/ShutdownThread.java

Comment: 10 seconds is not really that great, you have no way of knowing who else is consuming cycles here so there's still no guarantee you will get a turn. Admittedly, 10s would probably be plenty in most cases, but without knowing for sure (that it is blocking on you or something) you can't really design around it.

Answer (score 20):

In addition to `ACTION_SHUTDOWN`, you should add `android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF` to your intent-filter.
`ACTION_SHUTDOWN` isn't always broadcast on some HTC devices (e.g. the Evo 4g).
To be more specific, if you choose Restart, `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` is broadcast, but if you choose Power Off, `QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF` is broadcast instead.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what Dave Webb said is the appropriate way to handle this:

**You can override the Android Activity Lifecycle functions**:

```
protected void onPause();
protected void onResume();
```

In most scenarios implementing these should be sufficient and will not require you to specifically handle the "power off" events.

There's plenty more information on the [Android Website](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html) and in the answer to [this lifecycle question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for).