# receive android device shutdown

Tags: android

How receive device shutdown? I mean any broadcast receiver for get device shutdown state.

User press shutdown button on device. Choose shutdown -> Recevier get it.

Any ideas about it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to get a notice when a user power off their Android phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190126/is-there-any-way-to-get-a-notice-when-a-user-power-off-their-android-phone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static final String ACTION_SHUTDOWN
```

**Since: API Level 4**

**Broadcast Action:** Device is shutting down. This is broadcast when the device is being shut down (completely turned off, not sleeping). Once the broadcast is complete, the final shutdown will proceed and all unsaved data lost. Apps will not normally need to handle this, since the foreground activity will be paused as well.

This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.

**Constant Value: "android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN"**

Comment: No, You don't need any permission for that.