# How to handle phone shutdown in my app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-fragments

I am using **Fragment** in my android app development.

I would like to clear the **back stack** of `FragmentTransaction` when user **shutdown** the phone during using my app.

How can I handle phone shutdown event in my app code?

Comment: Why would you want to treat a phone shutdown differently from a normal exit of your application?

Comment: Question was already mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190126/is-there-any-way-to-get-a-notice-when-a-user-power-off-their-android-phone