# Detect Android phone shut down when low battery

Tags: android

I want to know in my app if the phone could turn off given the battery might be low. I am doing some client / server data exchange.

There seems to be broadcast action [ACTION_SHUTDOWN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN). Will this broadcast be sent if the phone may turn off due to critically low battery ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your application can get that message if you implement a BroadcastReceiver class like the one below.

```
public class ShutdownReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
  {
    //Insert your code here
  }
}
```

and do't forget to add the following in your manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />
```

and this:

```
 <receiver android:name=".ShutdownReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

You can also do the same for ACTION_BATTERY_LOW.

Comment: the DEVICE_POWER permission is only granted to system apps?

Comment: I was able to get it to work without needing to add the DEVICE_POWER permission -- seems not to be required. Also as noted [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448304/handling-phone-shutdown-event-in-android here, `action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF"` should be included in the intent-filter.