# Running Android Application In Background All Time

Tags: android

I have application which have timers and if the timers are stopped the application will wont work I need to keep the application on all time even when the app is turn off (I know doesn't makes sense) and also to save the files if the phone is switched down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I need to keep the application on all time even when the app is turn off`

You can you  [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). Its for the same purpose.

`Save the files if the phone is switched down`

You can receive an intent [ACTION_SHUTDOWN](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN) in the broadcast receiver, when phone is about to switch off. Then you can do whatever you want to do there. See [Is there any way to receive a notification when the user powers off the device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190126/is-there-any-way-to-receive-a-notification-of-when-a-user-powers-off-his-her-and) for details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok and with Service if the player press the back button the app will be close and not runned in background right ?

Comment: If you read the link hat I gave ( Service) it mentions `facility for the application to tell the system about something it wants to be doing in the background (even when the user is not directly interacting with the application).`. So Service runs in the background as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you investigate [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

A service can run in the background continuously.

Comment: also save the data after turning off the phone ?