# How to automatically kill app in background when mobile is shutting down?

Tags: android

How to logout  my android application  automatically when mobile getting shutdown?
I want to stop or close or logout  my android application which in running in background in android when mobile getting is shutdown.

Is it possible? If so how to achieve this?
Any links will be appreciated.

Comment: how do you perform a logout? What do you do to logout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen for the following intent actions in your receiver/service:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF" />
```

For more info, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2190184/966550).

---

Hope this helps. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a broadcast listener for

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF" />
```

and in onReceive perform logout action

You can also use `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver which will notify when phone booting is completed

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
public class ReceiverForPowerOff extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Insert code here for logout
    }

}
```

**In manifest:**

```
<receiver android:name=".ReceiverForPowerOff">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```