# Nativescript - What event is triggered when a mobile device is attempted to be switched off?

Tags: angular, mobile, cross-platform, nativescript

I'm trying to develop a cross platform application using Angular+Nativescript. I need to capture the battery percentage of a mobile device when it is attempted to be switched off.

I have obtained the nativescript plugin to capture the battery levels. But I need to know in which event will I be able to capture the mobile switching off action and store the battery level before it happens.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible on iOS.

On Android you can achieve this by listening to the `android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN` and `android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF` events. Many questions have already been asked about this subject, so I would recommend you have a [look at other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190126/is-there-any-way-to-receive-a-notification-when-the-user-powers-off-the-device/2190184#2190184) to learn more about these events.

You can find information about [how to register a BroadcastReceiver using NativeScript here.](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/application#android-broadcast-receiver)